# Is there a way to click on anchor link

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

Please help me as the anchor tag looks like the below

```
<a title ="excel" class="activelink"style="Text-Decoration: none; onclick="$find('ReportViewerControl').exportReport('Excelopenxml');" href ="javascript:void(0)" alt="Excel" _selected="true"> Excel</a>
```

This doesn't have any document id or class..  Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is a reporting website where we generate the report and click on save option where we will get the option to download reports

Comment: Could you explain your problem in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

I try to check your HTML code and found that it contains the class but it can be possible that many other elements on the page using the same class. If you try to access the link using that class then it can possible that you click the incorrect element on the page.

We can see that the link contains the ' Excel' text. We can try to loop through all the links on the page and try to match the `innerHTML` to find that specific link.

Example:

```
'Below is code to loop through anchor tags, find the specific link, and click it.
    Set elems = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    For Each elem In elems
        If (elem.innerHTML) = " Excel" Then
            elem.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next elem
```

Output:

[image]

In a similar way, you can also match other attributes from the anchor tag that may also help to click the link.

**Note:** This code example is for clicking the specific link on a page. It may not help you to automate the file download.

Further, you can try to modify the code example as per your own requirements.